# Controller with ngResource method called indefinitely

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I decided to start learning AngularJS by making a simple app.

The server-side application is built with ExpressJs, but the resource used below (*/movie/:id*) are not implemented yet, so pointing to this URL will result in a *404 (Not Found) error*. So only getting '/' works.

I wanted to see how a $resource behaved so I made this simple test :

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory("Movie", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/movie/:id");
})

app.controller("MovieCtrl", function($scope, Movie) {
    $scope.test = function () {
        Movie.query();
        return 42;
    } 
});
```

And my template file :

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MovieCtrl">
        {{ test() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

As expected the template is rendered and '42' is properly displayed, but if I watch  the console in the Chrome developer tools I keep seeing the following error (also as expected):

```
GET http://localhost/movie 404 (Not Found)
```

**But this message is printed indefinitely and never stops**, as if my Movie resource keeps trying to reach */movie* even though after a hundred tries it still keeps failing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Movie.query()` calls `$scope.$apply()` after it gets response from the server.

Everytime `$scope.$apply()` is called, angular does dirty checking (which again invokes `test` and therefore calls `Movie.query()` again) to find out if anything has changed. This causes an infinite loop.

move `Movie.query()` out from the `test()`, and this should work.

Let me make myself clear - take look at this pseudo code:

```
var watches = ['$scope.test()'];
var previous = {};
var values = {};

$rootScope.$apply = function(){
  previous = values;
  values = {};
  var dirty = false;  
  for (var i =0;i<watches.length;i++){
      var expression = watches[i];
      values[expression] = value = eval(expression);
      if(value!=previous)dirty=true;
  }
  if(dirty)$rootScope.$apply();
}

Movie.query = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $rootScope.$apply();
   },300);
}

$scope.test = function(){
   Movie.query();
   return 42;
}
```

so the flow is following:

1. $scope.apply();
2. $scope.test();
3. Movie.query(); -> `setTimeout($scope.apply,100)` (back to beginning );

and so on..

Comment: Is the dirty checking performed to see if the result of the test method returned has not changed ? If so the Movie.query() does not alter this result.

Comment: Yes, but `Movie.query()` triggers `$scope.$apply()` (when the data comes back from the server) which checks if `test()` has changed. During this check, `test()` triggers another `Movie.query()` which again triggers `scope.$apply()`, and so on.